# Problems making an AJAX call in a Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am running into some issues with the AJAX portion of a Wordpress site feature that takes a zip code entered on a form uses a PHP function to find if the zip code refers to a specific location and returns a permalink to that location.

My first question was about the form I built. Right now I have the form-action blank because I don't want the form to really go anywhere, just make the AJAX call. Is there anything extra I need to do in the form to indicate the data entered should go to an AJAX function?

```
<form id="zipcode" action="" method="post"><input class="form-control search-input" autocomplete="off" name="zipcode" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" />
```

The next question I have is about the filter function in my functions.php file. I'm not sure exactly how to go about getting the form data passed inot the filter data, this is what I have tried below, I also included the zip_search function which returns the permalink.

```
/**
* LOCATION SEARCH FILTER AJAX
* 
* call location search filter ajax
*
* @return ajax json data via function.
*/
add_action( 'wp_ajax_locations_search', 'prefix_ajax_locations_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_locations_search', 'prefix_ajax_locations_search' ); //used for handling AJAX requests from unauthenticated users

function prefix_ajax_zip_search_filter() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
    $zipcode = $_POST[ 'zipcode' ];

    //return our filtered location data
    echo zip_search($zipcode);

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response 
}

//Function that contains zip code search functionality
function zip_search($userZip){

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'Locations'
    );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 

if( $wp_query->have_posts() ): while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
      $zipField=get_field('zip_codes_services');

          $zipString = $zipField . ', ';        

          $array = explode(', ' , $zipString); //split string into array seperated by ', '

        foreach($array as $value) //loop over values
        {

            if($value==$userZip){
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                $permalink=get_permalink($post_id);                 
                return ($permalink); //print
           }    

        }
       endwhile; 
       wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;
}
```

Lastly I created a separate js folder containing the below scripts.js seen below, for now I just wanted it to redirect to an example site if my form is not blank. Right now the only thing that happens when I submit a zipcode into the form is the page refreshes.

```
    $("form#zipcode").on("submit", function(event) {
    $('form#zipcode .clear-button').addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();

    zipcode_search(zip_search_filter());
    });    

function zipcode_search(zip_search_filter) {
    //add ajax loader
    $("form#zipcode .ajax-content-loader").addClass("active");

    //process the form
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: ajaxcall.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: "locations_search", //calls the function in the functions.php file
            zip_search_filter: zip_search_filter
        },
        success: function(response) {
            //redirect to new page
            if (response != "") {
                    alert("You will now be redirected.");
                    window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
            }

            //remove the loader
            $("#zipcode .ajax-content-loader").removeClass(
                "active"
            );
        }
    });

    return false; //prevents the form from submitting to a new page.
}
```

Does anyone have experience with AJAX calls in Wordpress, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: How/where are you calling the `zipcode_search()` Javascript function?

Comment: Hmm ok so I need to find a way to call that when the form is submitted.

Comment: @PatrickQ so I added: `$("form#zipcode").on("submit", function(event) {
    $('form#zipcode .clear-button').addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
    
    zipcode_search(zip_search_filter);
    });` to my `scripts.js` file still nothing when my form submits. Do I have to make a form id?

Comment: This is a legitimate question and I do not mean it insultingly: Do you know what actually `$("form#zipcode")` means/does?

Comment: @PatrickQ No offense taken. My thinking from looking at examples is that it is running the JavaScript function when the form with the name `zipcode` is submitted then clearing it after submission. I'm very new to JavaScript and asynchronous programming so I could very well be wrong.

Comment: First, a lot of what you are using here is the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/), not just native Javascript. I suggest you take some time and review their documentation.  Second, the snippet that I pointed out looks for a `form` element with the `id` of "zipcode". Note that `id` is not the same thing as `name`. In the HTML that you posted in your question, your form does not have an `id` at all.

Comment: @PatrickQ so the `$("form#zipcode")` is retrieves server data for `zipcode elements` without reloading the whole page. Ok I see. I will add an ID.

Comment: No. Please review the [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page. You really need to understand the basics of the tools/languages that you're using before you start doing more complex things.

Comment: Some of what you said in your last comment wasn't quite correct, but the edit to your question should now be giving you different (and positive) results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to add a form id:

Then I made a number of edits, in `functions.php` :

```
/**
* LOCATION SEARCH FILTER AJAX
* 
* call location search filter ajax
*
* @return ajax json data via function.
*/
add_action( 'wp_ajax_locations_search', 'prefix_ajax_locations_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_locations_search', 'prefix_ajax_locations_search' ); //used for handling AJAX requests from unauthenticated users

function prefix_ajax_locations_search() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
    $zipcode = $_POST[ 'zipcode' ];

    //return our filtered location data
    echo zip_search($zipcode);

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response 
}

//Function that contains zip code search functionality
function zip_search($userZip){

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'Locations'
    );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 

if( $wp_query->have_posts() ): while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
      $zipField=get_field('zip_codes_services');

          $zipString = $zipField . ', ';        

          $array = explode(', ' , $zipString); //split string into array seperated by ', '

        foreach($array as $value) //loop over values
        {

            if($value==$userZip){
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                $permalink=get_permalink($post_id);                 
                return ($permalink); //print
           }    

        }
       endwhile; 
       wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;
}
```

I also had to include my custom jquery file and my AJAX file in the `enqueue_scripts` function `functions.php`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-js', 'ajaxcall', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

Finally in `scripts.js` I made the following changes and instead of redirecting to http://example.com I redirected to the permalink I get from my `zip_search` function seen above.

```
/*
 * Put all your regular jQuery in here.
 * Within this funtion you can use the namespace $ instead of jQuery
 * ex. use this $('#id') ... NOT jQuery('#id')
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("form#zipcode").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('form#zipcode .clear-button').addClass('active');

        //get the entered zipcode value to pass through our function.
        var zipcode = $(this).find('input[name="zipcode"]').val();

        zipcode_search(zipcode);

    });    

    function zipcode_search(zipcode) {
        //add ajax loader
        $("form#zipcode .ajax-content-loader").addClass("active");

        //process the form
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url: ajaxcall.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "locations_search", //calls the function in the functions.php file
                zipcode: zipcode
            },
            success: function(response) {
                //redirect to new page
                if (response != "") {
                        //alert("You will now be redirected.");

                        window.location = response;
                }

                //remove the loader
                $("#zipcode .ajax-content-loader").removeClass(
                    "active"
                );
            }
        });

        return false; //prevents the form from submitting to a new page.
    }

}); /* end of as page load scripts */
```

Doing all of this solved my problem and the search form now works how I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the form is submitting before your functions are called. Try moving `event.preventDefault()` so it is called first, like so:

```
$("form#zipcode").on("submit", function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //call this first
$('form#zipcode .clear-button').addClass('active');

zipcode_search(zip_search_filter());
});
```

Check your syntax, `=!` should instead be `!=`;

```
//correct syntax
if (data != "") {
    alert("You will now be redirected.");
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
}
```

Also, your `success` function returns `response`, but you are referencing `data`. Change the code so that the proper object is referenced:

```
 success: function(response) {
        //redirect to new page
        if (response != "") {
                alert("You will now be redirected.");
                window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
        }
```

or...

```
 success: function(data) {
        //redirect to new page
        if (data != "") {
                alert("You will now be redirected.");
                window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
        }
```

Comment: I just changed it to correct syntax `!=` but still nothing happens when I submit the form.

Comment: I just make the suggested edits to the JavaScript, also updated my post above. Still having the same issue of the page not redirecting on form submission. Thinking it may be a problem in the php filter function.

Comment: I just edited my answer, try moving `event.preventDefault();` so that it is called immediately upon form submission. If that still does not work, please provide the live site URL so I can take a closer look.