# Using AJAX to pass in sessionStorage data in a WordPress site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make a variable out of data from `sessionStorage` that saves a post id when certain location pages are visited. Then use AJAX to pass this data to a PHP function that uses the post id to display location specific data (local phone numbers, location based pricing, etc) to the user anywhere in the site for the duration of the session, or until they visit another location page.

The idea that on page load the the post id  is set in `sessionStorage` and then a JavaScript function in my `scripts.js` file is called that gets the `sessionStorage` and puts it into a variable, like: `var postid = sessionStorage.getItem('postid');`

Then in my `functions.php` I'll have a function that accesses this data like:

```
function prefix_ajax_post_id() {
 //post id passed in from AJAX
 //call functions that use post id

 wp_die();
}
```

I'm just not really sure how to structure the AJAX part of it. I created other AJAX functions in this site that takes in data from a form with `POST` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53053433/8206741 but not sure what to do in this particular situation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  If you want to use a value in session storage on an ajax request, you just do it.  It's a variable like any other variable.  You get the value off of it and put it on the ajax requets.

Comment: @Taplar Ok well how can I access that data from a php function. Can I make the JavaScript function post the data on page load and then access in the PHP function something like this: `$post_id = $_POST[ 'postid' ];`

Comment: You might be better off here revising your post and telling us what you're trying to accomplish, it seems that you might not be asking quite the right question.

However, if what you really want is to access a php varible in javascript, that's pretty easy though generally frowned upon.

var x = '<?php echo $_SESSION['some_value']; ?>';

Comment: @Blaise yes, that's exactly what you'd do

Comment: @Difster I edited, hopefully it better explains what I am trying to do and I'm actually trying to go the other way and access a JavaScript variable in PHP.

Comment: Ok, for what you're describing, you wouldn't want to be storing a session value in javascript. You could do something like give your location pages a custom post type then store the location when that post type gets launched and just use add_filter to display the data where needed.

Comment: @Difster The location pages are already custom post types and the idea was to save the postid so that I could use it to access ACF fields I created outside of the location pages. So for instance `$phone=get_field("phone_number", $postid)` so a location specific number would appear in the header and stay for continuation of the session.

Comment: Are you familiar with the add_filter() functionality in WordPress? If not, look in to it, that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

> not really sure how to structure the AJAX part of it

```
$.post('/some/url', { postid: postid }).done(function(data) {
    // do stuff when its done (successfully)
    // 'data' variable will contain what the server returns (if any)
}).fail(function(resp) {
    // do stuff if it fails 
    // 'resp' might have some info in it
}).always(function() {
    // do this no matter what
});
```

Just make sure `'/some/url'` is changed to suite.

The second param passed to `$.post()` is a JSON object that will form your `$_POST` variables.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: So here it looks like I have to post to a particular URL but I need to to post on whatever page the user visits. Is there a way to specify that? Do I use `url: ajaxcall.ajaxurl` somewhere?

Comment: It's a good idea to write some pseudo code and get your ideas in front of you before you start coding. https://edgecoders.com/the-mistakes-i-made-as-a-beginner-programmer-ac8b3e54c312 (See #1)

Comment: I'm not going to ask you why you want to do that, figuring out the logic is what makes it fun :) But you could just replace `'/some/url'` with `ajaxcall.ajaxurl` if you must.